# Ad-hoc Wi-Fi: disable wireless comms while keeping interface up

Tags: wifi, socket, iw, ad-hoc-network

TLDR: I want to prevent wireless communication with peers on a Raspberry Pi ad-hoc WiFi network but without bringing it down or disabling the interface. This is to simulate the nodes getting out of range of each other.

I have a wireless network of three Raspberry Pis running an ad-hoc network ("PiFi"). On each Pi, the interface `wlan0` is assigned a static IP address of `10.0.0.x`, where `x` is 1, 2, or 3. For debugging purposes, the Pis are connected to an Ethernet switch so I can control them over SSH. This wired network uses `192.168.2.*`, with addresses assigned by DHCP from my laptop. I use the following commands on each device to enable the network. (Note that I am also running BATMAN to handle layer 2 routing on the mesh network, but I do not believe this is relevant.)

Commands on startup:

```
iw wlan0 set type ibss
ip link set wlan0 up
iw wlan0 ibss join "PiFi" 2432
```

`/etc/dhcpcd.conf`:

```
interface wlan0
static ip_address=10.0.0.x/24
```

My problem is that I need to test how each node in the *wireless* network performs when it is wirelessly out of range of the other nodes (my software has TCP connections that ought to time out and reattempt connections periodically). This is difficult to test by physically moving the Pis out of range of each other. Unfortunately, the following things do not work for me:

- Disabling the interface (`ip link set wlan0 down`). This disallows binding to `10.0.0.x`.
- Turning off the transmitter (`iwconfig wlan0 txpower off`). Same problem (can't bind).
- Turning down the power on the transmitter (`iwconfig wlan0 txpower 1mW`). Devices still communicate easily over the air because they're close to each other.
- Switching the ESSID on one node (`iw wlan0 ibss leave; iw wlan0 ibss join "FakeFi" 2432`). This has weird effects. It works sometimes, but often the connecting end of a socket occasionally (1 out of 5 times) binds to `192.168.2.*`. (Forcing the *connecting* socket to bind to `10.0.0.x` fails with `EADDRNOTAVAIL` as soon as the leave/join occurs).

I need a way to keep the interface up, so my sockets bind to the correct addresses, but somehow disable actual wireless communication. In theory, this could be done by disabling the physical antenna or setting the transmit power to 0, but I haven't found a way to do this. I'm open to any sort of solution.

Comment: What about a firewall rule?